# Display hierarchical Multidimensional Array with parent child numbering

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, hierarchical-clustering

I have a multidimensional array which has parent child relationship.

I want to display this as a list of numerical value representing their parents in an appropriate order.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Category 1
            [id] => 6
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Category 2
                            [id] => 7
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [name] => cricket1
                                            [id] => 19
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [name] => cricket2
                                                            [id] => 21
                                                            [children] => 
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => another category
                            [id] => 15
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [name] => new 1
                                            [id] => 18
                                            [children] => 
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Category 3
            [id] => 8
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => new category
                            [id] => 11
                            [children] => 
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Sazzad
            [id] => 9
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Mahmud
                            [id] => 10
                            [children] => 
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I want to show this array as given below :

```
    1.      Category 1
    1.1     Category 2
    1.1.1   cricket1
    1.1.1.1 cricket2
    1.2     another category
    1.2.1   new 1
    2.      Category 3
    2.1     new category
    3.      Sazzad
    3.1     Mahmud
```

How Can I achieve this numbering system using PHP??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yap... Here is the url of the array : http://pastebin.com/ixcRuvAf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use simple recursive function:

```php
function makeOneLevelArray($in, &$out, $prefixLevel = '') {
    $level = 1;
    foreach ($in as $v) {
        $out[] = $prefixLevel . $level . ' ' . $v['name'];
        if (!empty($v['children'])) {
            makeOneLevelArray($v['children'], $out, $prefixLevel . $level . '.');
        }
        $level++;
    }
}

$outputArray = array();
makeOneLevelArray($inputArray, $outputArray);
print_r($outputArray);
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/367642)</kbd>